# jquery attr return undefined unexpected in chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

this question is not about how to write chrome extension

when I run this on chrome console,it works fine,returns string as expected..

but when i add this to the script as a chrome extension,it return undefined

html:

```
<div id="articleCommentDiv" style="border:0px;" class="widget wbox" context="
                    {
                        &quot;requestType&quot;:&quot;ajax&quot;,
                        &quot;path&quot;:&quot;/产品专区论&quot;,
                        &quot;articleId&quot;:699286466,
                        &quot;targetChannel&quot;:&quot;新闻中心&quot;,
                        &quot;targetMenu&quot;:&quot;产品专区&quot;
                    }
                    " load="true">
```

manifest.json：

```
{
  "name": "Page Redder",
  "description": "Make the current page red",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["test1.js","jquery-1.11.1.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Make this page red"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

test1.js:

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  results=$("#articleCommentDiv").attr("context");
   alert(typeof(results));
});
```

Comment: Sounds like the selector isn't finding the element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery attr return undefined unexpected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050114/jquery-attr-return-undefined-unexpected)

Comment: Do **NOT** evade question closures by posting an exact duplicate. "Closed" status means that you still have time to appeal, by editing your question and/or stating why it isn't a duplicate in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong load order in the manifest.

Scripts are loaded in the order they are specified in the manifest. As a result, your `test1.js` loads before jQuery is ready. Just swap them around.